# Cannot replace views in swift for OS X

Tags: macos, swift

probably I don't understand how views works in swift. I'm trying to replace view in my LoginViewController but nothing is happening.

```
@IBAction func loginBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    let authViewController = AuthViewController(nibName: "AuthView", bundle: nil)!
    let appDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    appDelegate.window.contentView.replaceSubview(self.view, with: authViewController.authView)
}
```

and my AppDelegate.swift

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var customView: NSView!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusMenu: NSMenu!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        let loginViewController = LoginViewController(nibName: "LoginView", bundle: nil)!

        window.contentView.addSubview(loginViewController.view)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but will it help if you tell frame after your replace subview?

```
let authViewController = AuthViewController(nibName: "AuthView", bundle: nil)!
let appDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

appDelegate.window.contentView.replaceSubview(self.view, with: authViewController.authView)
authViewController.view.frame = (appDelegate.window.contentView as! NSView).frame
```

Answer (score 0):

loginViewController will be deallocated right away as nobody is holding it. Same is true for authViewController

=> VIEWS don't hold their VIEW CONTROLLERS so the views will go away right away

make a member variable to hold on to them

Comment: note: this might not be the root cause for YOUR issue but it is a might issue that you should  change before further investigation. -- but it also might solve this :D

Comment: could you tell me where can I find more informations about this? there is little tutorials on the web

Comment: it is how arc works ... stuff is released whenever a strong reference disappears, when the last one goes it is deallocated. ... read up on arc maybe!?